# Spring Boot only OTP login NO password

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, oauth-2.0, registration, one-time-password

In the spring boot rest application (frontend end is Angular), Looking to implement OTP-based login. **without** any password.
Every time a user needs to log in using a mobile/email number and the OTP sends it to the mobile/email.

The first-time login, treat as registration and create a user in DB, and further same user login will fetch profile data from DB.

Similar to
https://www.cowin.gov.in/
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upon registration, get the user's email and create a user entry in your DB.

When user clicks Login present them with a screen to enter their email. Upon submitting email, check if it exists in the backend. If it does, generate an OTP and save it to the user e.g if using a SQL DB, save the OTP in a column in the user's row. Send the user an email with the OTP and update the UI to display the input field for the OTP.

When the user enters the OTP, verify that what they entered is what is stored in DB. If they match, fetch profile data. If not, display error message.